# How to apply early stopping when using voting regressor with xgboost and another model

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am combing the efforts of multiple models via sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html

In general, when building model with `xgboost`. I use early stopping in the fit method in order to avoid overfitting. How can I apply the same `early stopping` when I combine the methods via voting regressor?

See my code below:

```
xgb_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=500, 
                         max_depth=4, 
                         learning_rate=0.1, 
                         reg_alpha=0.001)

lasso_reg = sklearn.linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)

randomforest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500,max_depth=4, verbose=2)

estimators= [('LASSO', lasso_reg), 
             ('RandomForest', randomforest), 
             ('XGBOOST', xgb_model)]

model = VotingRegressor(estimators= estimators, verbose=True)
...
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If I was using `xgboost` alone, I would do:

```
model.fit(X_train, 
          y_train, 
          eval_metric="mae", 
          eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_val, y_val)],
          early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. However, I think fit function of VotingRegressor doesn't have eval_set parameters because most of the estimator in sklearn are designed to be used on cross_validate function.

I think you could fit your xgboost model with eval_set first. Then, fit VotingRegressor with empty xgboost model (no params) and change xgboost model by
.estimators_ params. However, it's not a neat solution because you have to do a few extra work after fit before you could use predict.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).